# iPhone - UITableview having a list of video thumbnails

Tags: iphone, xcode4, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

How can we list video thumbnails on a UItableview.I have the link for the videos (from an external server) in JSON array. Please provide me with some insights or references.

Thanks,

Comment: -1 for gimme the codez request

Comment: I do not understand what you say ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by generating thumbnails of each video beforehand and sending them down in your JSON array from the server. Any type of local processing of videos would be a huge performance hit.

Comment: Meaning we tap on the image and the video then plays in the next screen . Just show a generic image of the videos or a small screen shot of it.